# Does VoltDB use compression?

Tags: database, compression, internals, voltdb

I reckon that VoltDB uses compression but I'm not sure about that. Mike Stonebraker, who is the main creator of VoltDB, used to work on Vertica, which uses compression heavily. I heard about a case when somebody loaded a few GB of sequential integers and after loading the data the database size was barely about 1 GB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VoltDB is designed for maximum throughput & transaction processing performance, so it does not compress data for tables, views, or indexes stored in memory.

We have a blog post on [database sizing](http://voltdb.com/blog/memory-database-sizing-%E2%80%93-throw-out-conventional-wisdom), or how you can estimate the size of RAM needed for a use case and schema.

Comment: Surely there are operations on certain data sets for which "maximum throughput" would be enhanced by some form of compression. Also I'm surprised the answer is simply "no". There most be some encoding techniques used in the Db that qualify as compression

Comment: VoltDB does use compression for snapshots (which are used for archiving data to disk, sending initial data to a node that is joining the cluster or to a replica cluster. However, the question was mainly about whether compression was used for the primary storage of user data (i.e. in memory) and VoltDB does not use compression for that.